# PHP - unique attribute for objects of a class

Tags: php, oop

I have this class

```
class MyClass{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    public function __construct ($id, $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$ob1 = new MyClass(1, 'earth');
$ob2 = new MyClass(2, 'sky');
$ob3 = new MyClass(3, 'ocean');
```

I want that my objects $ob1, $ob2 and $ob3 have a different attribute $id. For example when i make this :

```
$ob4 = new MyClass(3, 'wood');
```

The code denies me to create the object

Thanks

Comment: No there is no database. it is just variables in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the ids in a `static` class property:

```
class MyClass {
    static private $ids = [];

    public function __construct($id) {
        if (in_array($id, self::$ids)) {
            throw new Exception("Object with id $id already constructed");
        }
        self::$ids[] = $id;
    }
}
```

Having said this, I would question the usefulness of this. It just sounds like a recipe for problems. You should keep track of unique data as part of some business logic and database interaction, probably not as something enforced on a language level.

Comment: Can be handy as a repository. You could even add a `static function getInstance($id)` that returns an object with that id from the static array, or constructs a new one if it doesn't exist yet. But whether this is really the best implementation for it.. Mwah..